# Two 4k Displays

Tags: displayport

I want to set up my machine with two 4k Displays. For that, I need to have a separate graphic card for each display as the Display Port only supports one Monitor with this resolution.

I have two of these graphic cards:

> Gefore VGA compatible controller: 
>   NVIDIA Corporation GK104 [GeForce GTX 760] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
>
> > ```
> >    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 2847
> >    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47
> >    Memory at f4000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
> >     Memory at d8000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=128M]
> >     Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
> >     I/O ports at d000 [size=128]
> >     [virtual] Expansion ROM at f5000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
> >     Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
> >     Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
> >     Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
> >     Capabilities: [b4] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
> >     Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
> >     Capabilities: [128] Power Budgeting <?>
> >     Capabilities: [600] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=024 <?>
> >     Kernel driver in use: nvidia
> > ```

Whats working is that I can set up one 4k Display and a 1920 Display on the first card. I also can use Xinerama from the nvidia-settings to get the two displays working together on the different graphic cards. But using the Xinerama setting my systems tells me I do not have any OpenGL support any more.

If I want to open the Display "tool" this is not working.

Is there any way to keep the 3D Support (e.g. for gaming) and to use two different graphic cards?

BR,
Pingu

Comment: I see [here](http://www.lesnumeriques.com/moniteur-ecran-lcd/dell-up3214q-p17963/test.html) that on Windows, in January 2014, 2x 4K display was badly supported by nvidia 332.21

Comment: Seems like a work in progress.  http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?px=MTY4MDI&page=news_item